# Enabling multi-touch in game?

Tags: xcode, multi-touch

I am creating a simple pong game in Xcode. I have a 2 player version and both paddles can be moved and function perfectly. The game is flawless except for the fact that you cannot move both paddles at the same time, rendering the 2 player mode useless.

How can I enable both paddles to be moved at the same time?
I've already tried selecting the "Multiple Touch" button in Interface Builder but it does nothing and im not quite sure it is even the correct route into enabling multi touch as I want it.

Also, my game is a View-Based Application if that matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience (which isn't that much).  You can create 2 UIViews for the 2 paddles, touching in one view will move one paddle, while touching in the other will move the other paddle.  I hope this helps.

If you don't know how to split the views, you can simply make it identify 2 touches

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch1 = [[event touchesForView:zone1] anyObject];
UITouch *touch2 = [[event touchesForView:zone2] anyObject];
if (touch1)
    touchOffset1 = paddle1.center.x - [touch1 locationInView:touch1.view].x;
if (touch2)
    touchOffset2 = paddle2.center.x - [touch2 locationInView:touch2.view].x;
}
```

This you can use, it probably isn't the most productive, but it does work if you can't figure out how to split the touches.

Comment: Hmm... I am quite a n00b at this and I don't know if I understand. If I create two UIViews, how do I add them to the existing paddles?

Comment: I updated my code above, maybe not the best implementation, but the fact of the matter is, you need 2 UIViews in order to know if player1 or player2 is trying to move their paddle.  If you only have 1 view, how will you ever know who is who?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I mis-read the question. Added code snippet.

Here's the code I use to extract all touches when I get a touchesBegan event:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
    NSUInteger nNumTouches = [touchesArray count];
    UITouch *touch;
    CGPoint ptTouch;
    for (int nTouch = 0;  nTouch < nNumTouches;  nTouch++)
    {
        touch = [touchesArray objectAtIndex:nTouch];
        ptTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        // Do stuff with the touch
    }
}
```

and similarly for touchesEnded and touchesMoved

Comment: Thanks for replying but I said I tried this and that it didn't work.

Comment: Whoops, sorry!
Are you sure your code is checking all the arrays in the set?

Comment: What exactly does that mean? This is my first real app btw... Thanks!

Comment: Well I tried adding this and personalizing it accordingly but it pretty much functions the same, if at all.

Comment: Hmmm... Could you describe your problem in detail? E.g. Touch with one finger, do you get the touchesBegan event? Now move that finger, do you get the touchesMoved event? Now add a second finger, do you get another touchesBegan event? Now move both fingers, which finger do you get touchesMoved events for?

Comment: The event occurs for the first paddle touched and attempting to move the other does nothing. I think that the other guy below me is correct saying I need two UIViews to distinguish who is who however I'm not sure how to do this the my existing project.

Comment: I don't use two UIViews, but if that works for you, that's cool. When you say the other "does nothing", do you not even get a touchesBegan event? That event should occur whenever you stick a new finger down.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

by default it is No